# Expand qualitative color palette for raster plot R

Tags: r, colors, raster

I want to expand a qualitative palette of colors in order to get a raster map with much more information.

I've been using the `rasterVis` package and with a particularly plot I need more colors than the `Paired` palette.

```
levelplot(...,
      par.settings = rasterTheme(region = brewer.pal(10,'Paired')), 
      at=seq(0,5000,500),
      ...)
```

With this configuration I get a raster going from 0 to 5000 by 200 units. The `rasterTheme` function let me use 10 discrete colors for the plot based on the `Paired` palette.

The `Paired` palette only has 12 colors and if I want 25 colors (for a raster going from 0 to 5000 by 200 units) I necessarily have to use a predefined palette which means use a sequential palette.

```
levelplot(...,
      par.settings = YlOrRdTheme, 
      at=seq(0,5000,200),
      ...)
```

How could I use 25 different colors for a non-sequential color palette? Should I create a color palette manually or is there a function to create random color palettes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The library [randomcoloR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomcoloR/randomcoloR.pdf) has two functions for creating random colors with arguments for selecting the number of colors you want. Example using the `distinctColorPalette` function:

```
# load the library
library(randomcoloR)

# define the number of colors
k <- 25

# generate the colors
colors <- distinctColorPalette(k = k)

# proof - plot the colors 
xleft <- seq(1,k,1)
xright <- xleft+1
ybottom <- rep(0,k)
ytop <- ybottom+1
plot(1, 1, xlim = c(0, k), type = "n", axes = FALSE, bty = "n", xlab = "", 
  ylab = "") 
rect(xleft = xleft, ybottom = ybottom, xright = xright, ytop = ytop, col = 
  colors, border = "white")
```